# ways of automatic capitalizing format in emails (webpage/outlook version)

Tags: email, text-formatting

Is there a way to automatically capitalize the 1st letters, 'I', special terms etc in emails? For lazy people not wanting to press 'shift' all the time.

Comment: Likely not but if there is it depends on the software you're using. So please don't be lazy in this situation and [edit] the question to add that info.

Comment: This is dependent on the software. Most software I've used does this already

Comment: @music2myear what software for example?

Comment: Outlook and Lotus Notes both do this. The built in mail client in Windows 10 does as well. So, as you've already been asked: what software are YOU using?

Comment: I'm not using any software, just a webpage version. For example, enter mail.harvard.edu and that's it. But I also use another one called outlook web access (owa)